# req.user is null when sending a request with axios to a backend route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to extract user data from a request sent by Axios to the backend after user being logged in. I'm surprised to get req.user =null.
This is the conole.log(req) notice that the token is being sent but user is defined to null. what could be the problem ?

```
token: 'abciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.ODgwODIzNjc3ZmYxOSIsImlhdCI6MTY4MTA5MjI4MCwiZXhwIjoxNjgxNjk3MDgwfQ.rJthdCLz7XoTOHEMZNNHaQ02CuFYDTEJQWJn4H7lZLo'
  },
  signedCookies: [Object: null prototype] {},
  route: Route {
    path: '/me',
    stack: [ [Layer], [Layer] ],
    methods: { get: true }
  },
  user: null,
```

This is the get request being sent :

```
// Load user
export const loadUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        
        dispatch({ type: LOAD_USER_REQUEST })
        const { data } = await axios.get('/me')
          
        dispatch({
            type: LOAD_USER_SUCCESS,
            payload: data.user
        })
```

the function in the controller to respond to this request is below:

```
//Get currently logged in user details  =>/me


 exports.getUserProfile = catchAssyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
        console.log("get user id ", req); 
        // if condition search which user is Logged in 
        console.log("search user id ", req.user); 
        const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
        res.status(200).json({
            succcess: true,
            user
        })
```